P-value in tbl_strata
I am working with a large data set, and in the following example, I would like to indent the numerical variables (Scores, Time, and Grade), bold the levels of color ("Blue", "Green", etc.), provide p-values with 3 digits, and bold those p-values < 0.5. Thanks!
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group = c("Control", "Intervention"),
                 level = c("Low", "Moderate", "High"),
                 color = rep(c("Green", "Yellow", "Red", 
                               "Blue", "White", "Purple"), 
                             each = 6),
                 Scores = runif(n = 180, 
                                min = 100, 
                                max = 1000),
                 Time = runif(n = 180, 
                              min = 0.5, 
                              max = 1),
                 Grade = runif(n = 180, 
                               min = 1, 
                               max = 10)
                 )

list("tbl_summary-fn:addnl-fn-to-run" = 
       function(x) {
         if (!is.null(x$by)) x <- add_p(x) 
         italicize_labels(x) 
       } 
     ) |>
  set_gtsummary_theme()


tbl <- df |>
  tbl_strata(strata = color,
             function(df) {
               df |>
                 tbl_strata(strata = level,
                            ~ tbl_summary(.x,
                                          by = group,
                                          statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
                            ) ) 
             },
             .combine_with = "tbl_stack") |>
  modify_header(label ~ "")
  
tbl


